# Converter todas strings para minúsculas

Tags: c#, .net, string, entity-framework, fluent-api

Existe uma maneira de configurar o `modelBuider`, para deixar minhas strings com caixa baixa? Por exemplo, quando eu quero que todas as meu dados do tipo `string`, seja no meu banco um `varchar`, eu faço a seguinte configuração:

```
 modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
                .Configure(p => p.HasColumnType("varchar"));
```

tem como fazer essas strings serem salvar todas minúsculas no meu banco?
e se não tem como fazer pelo `modelbuider`, qual seria a forma mais eficiente?

Comment: Tenho quase certeza que não, se tiver, eu queria entender que sentido isso tem. Me parece que está apenas procurando uma solução mágica que não tem sentido. A forma correta é você fazer na mão quando precisa. Pode criar uma função que abstraia isso se for conveniente.

Comment: A verdade é que minha aplicação esta salvando tudo da maneira q o usuário digita, então se ele digitar asssim :(DigITAçÃO), vai salvar dessa maneira.. no caso eu teria que fazer o conversão para cada dado? supomos que eu tenho um form com 100 campos, eu tenho que fazer a transformação  de cada campo 1 a 1 ?

Comment: Exatamente isto. Qual o problema? É bem verdade quem nem sempre isso dará certo, porque pode normalizar coisas que deveriam ter caixa diferente mesmo e você matará isso, está tomando decisões que não deveriam ser sua. Se for algum campo muito específico, ok, mas se vai fazer isso de for ma generalizada é quase certo que está fazendo algo errado. Tem um monte de coisa que você faz um por um. Acho que vou responder daqui a pouco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fui dar uma pesquisada para ter certeza que não tinha nada já que esses *frameworks* por vezes gostam de fazer mágicas, embora este caso eu acho que seria muito sem sentido fazê-lo. Realmente não tem nada que possa configurar isto, ainda bem.

Como eu já disse em comentário não faz sentido ligar isso para todos os campos, ou até mesmo fazê-lo manualmente em todos. Eu já vi alguns softwares que o fazem e fica horrível, desvirtuando o que digitou o usuário que tem mais condições de determinar o que é certo. Em geral vai normalizar algo que não deveria para evitar algum possível abuso, se quer dificultar um abuso indique que algo possivelmente está abusando de caixa alta, mas deixe o usuário fazê-lo, se for o caso crie um *log*, mande um alerta pra alguma auditoria, mas não tome decisão pelo usuário quando não tem condições de fazer isto.

Se tiver algum raro caso que deseja isto normalmente é mais adequado tratar na entrada de dados, pela máscara ou validação. Em algum caso bem mais específico poderia fazer isso no modelo ou banco de dados.

Se for fazer no modelo então trate a propriedade para fazer assim, ou seja, crie uma lógica que toda vez que atribuir uma valor na propriedade a caixa seja normalizada, algo assim:

```
string descricao;
public string Descricao { get => descricao; set => descricao = value.ToLower(); }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/ToLower.cs).

Possivelmente deve ter alguma outra lógica de validação e normalização.

Se não quer fazer isso pode personalizar o [`SaveChanges()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges?view=entity-framework-6.2.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) do `DbContext` herdando em um contexto seu, mas duvido que seja melhor que a solução acima. Se o fizer você trata o objeto aí antes de salvar.

E sim, em qualquer caso você precisa fazer um por um, não tem mágica. Programar é dizer o que cada coisa faz. Claro, existe uma coisa que se aproxima de mágica, você pode usar reflexão, um recurso que pode tratar várias coisas de uma forma padronizada, mas aí ou você faz todos campos `string` agirem igual ou monta um sistema de anotações pra dizer que quer que faça isso naquele campo, o que provavelmente dará o mesmo trabalho de mandar fazer na propriedade como demonstrei acima, com chance de algo dar errado e ficar muito mais lento, que são os dois pontos negativos principais da reflexão, então não faça.

A outra possibilidade é mudar o dado manualmente, um por um, antes de salvar, assim não tem que criar seu próprio contexto nem colocar a lógica na propriedade, mas isso só faz sentido se for para realizar a normalização de caixa em algum ponto específico do código e não nos demais.